# Laravel Website multiple homepage. User can change

Tags: php, laravel

I want to know the way to use my multiple homepage design in Laravel. And User can switch homepage design from site settings like wordpress. Can anyone help me to find the way to make laravel website with multiple home page system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is quite general so I'll share my personal approach:

I create several template folders in my view directory with the same blade file structure inside.

Then from the Controller, I just change the call to the view according to the requested template:

```
return view($template_name . '.index');
```